# перенос БД MySQL PHPMyAdmin сохранились старые ссылки

Tags: php, mysql, сервер, phpmyadmin, hosting

Я перенес БД и тему Wordpress с локального на удаленный сервер, все подключил, но не могу зайти на сайт т.к. меня редиректит на мой локальный адрес. Что я сделал не так и как это исправить?

Comment: Исправить пути в БД? прописать **временно** в конфиг вордпреса оверрайд урла?

Comment: Варианты: 1) неверный конфиг 2) неверные урлы в БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправьте `siteurl` и `home` в таблице `wp_options`, заменив имя локального хост на текущий.

Comment: Да, уже нашел, хотел написать как раз, спасибо)